# Facebook Share API and permission list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebooks Android SDK (4.14) to post images to my Facebook wall. I am using the following code

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitMap).build();
SharePhotoContent share = new   SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
ShareApi.share(share,null);
```

This works fine for me. I am just looking for a possibility to pass as parameter this lists of friends who are allowed to see this image.

Is this possible with the Share API?

Regards

Michael

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: what will be a possible alternative? using the Graph API instead?

Comment: Yes, when you upload photos via API, you can specify the privacy while doing so. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating